# Can starting regular exercise cause a breathing issue?

Tags: cardio

Hi I have just started doing regular cardiovascular exercise but I have found that I am sometimes struggling to feel satisfied when taking breaths and need to really breathe deeply or yawn but it still does not always feel satisfying.
Please note this is not during or even just after exercise, only when I have stopped exercise after many hours and have fully recovered.
Could it be due to the exercise or a coincidence and something unrelated?

Comment: As suggested, go and get checked out by Doctor.  If is exercise induced asthma, you will feel better exercising when you have a pump

Answer (score 7):

Both my wife and my daughter have *exercise-induced bronchoconstriction*, also known as *exercise induced asthma*, and what you are describing sounds like what they deal with.  Go to a doctor to determine exactly what the problem you are experiencing truly is.

If it does happen to be exercise induced asthma, the doctor will give you an inhaler so that you can use it when your chest begins to tighten up.  That will allow you to exercise.

But the short answer is that is *not* normal to have breathing *problems* during exercise.  The typical shortness of breath that comes from vigorous exercise returns to normal rather quickly after rest.  Much sooner than the hours you are referring to.

Comment: The technical term is EIB, exercise induced bronchorestriction. Exercise doesn't cause asthma, but it can be an asthma trigger, hence the differentiation. I have EIB, but fortunately in my case, the only effect is post hard exercise bouts.